# Is Ar no Surge related to Ar Tonelico?

Tags: ar-tonelico, ar-nosurge

In the description for *Ar no Surge: Ode to an Unborn Star*, it talks about how song and music are used as magic and for character development.

> **AR Nosurge Ode To An Unborn Star PS3** is a Fantasy, Sci-fi, '7 Dimension' RPG, that takes place in a world where music and song can create magic.
>
> [...]
>
> **Ar Nosurge: Ode to an Unborn Star** has a unique character development system that focuses more on the bonds/ relationships between the main characters than their success in missions and battles, as the player's party grows stronger if the characters have a closer relationship.

Source: [Ozgameshop](http://www.ozgameshop.com/ps3-games/ar-nosurge-ode-to-an-unborn-star-ps3-game-with-misogi-dlc)

Now, this sounds much like the *Ar Tonelico* series, which talks about how music is used as magic and how you need to develop the character's relationships with one another to develop their strength. Also, both games were developed by Gust.

This makes me wondering: Are the 2 games are related story-wise? If they are, when does *Ar no Surge: Ode to an Unborn Star* occur in relation to *Ar Tonelico*?

Comment: Ar no Surge is a prequel to Ar Tonelico, based on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_nosurge)

Answer (score 1):

Warning, some spoilers for Ar Nosurge are below:

Ar Nosurge is set in the same universe as Ar Tonelico, but not on the same planet as Ar Tonelico (mostly, two of the main characters do visit Ar Ciel, the planet in Ar Tonelico). It is also a prequel to Ar Tonelico (the plot of Ar Nosurge takes place around 700 to 800 years before Ar Tonelico).

Despite being set on a different 'planet', there is a major story link between the two, as it deals with the origin of the Teru tribe in Ar Tonelico. You also meet a major character from Ar Tonelico in Ar Nosurge.

Answer (score 0):

Ar nosurge takes place roughly 735 years before Ar tonelico: Melody of Elemia, going by the clues the game leaves and the information revealed from the official setting encyclopedias.